# rewrite {query}.m3u8 to m3u8.php?v={query}

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Template:

```
{query}.m3u8
```

Example:

```
m3u8.php?v=AAAA-000
```

This is what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.m3u8 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ m3u8.php?v=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^.]*)\.m3u8/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m3u8.php?v=%1 [NC,L]
```

OR if you want to check if requested filename in browser is present in your system then add extra condition like:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^.]*)\.m3u8/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m3u8.php?v=%1 [NC,L]
```